# The elements of the vector space $\mathbf{R}^{[0, 1]}$ are real-valued functions on $[0, 1]$, ...

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

The textbook *Linear Algebra Done Right*, third edition, by Sheldon Axler, says the following on page 14:

> The elements of the vector space $\mathbf{R}^{[0, 1]}$ are real-valued functions on $[0, 1]$, ...

What exactly does it mean to say that the functions are "on $[0, 1]$"? Does that mean that the *domain* of the functions is $[0, 1]$?

I would greatly appreciate it if people would please clarify this.

Comment: Yes. It means that $\mathbb{R}^{[0,1]}$ is the set of functions $f:[0,1]\to \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: this is kind of notation in the old book of algebra $F^E$ means the space of application (Or linear application ...it's depends on the context .) such that  $f: E \rightarrow F$

Comment: It's not just notation: the set of sequences $(a_n)$ can be thought of as countable products $A^\mathbb{N}$ or as functions $a:\mathbb{N}\to A$.

Comment: @WoolierThanThou Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Should [0,1] be thought of as a set of discrete values, or as all real numbers between 0 and 1? In general, does it depend on the context?